# How Request Session is maintained in Singleton Services

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am configuring my services at startup file like below. Multiple calls will be made to DocClient to get response. As its singleton there will be a shared object thought the server. How it ensure and maintain the session for all the request.

services.AddSingleton()

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core maintains session state by providing a cookie to the client that contains a session ID, which is sent to the app with each request. The app uses the session ID to fetch the session data.

**Session state exhibits the following behaviors:**

Because the session cookie is specific to the browser, sessions aren't shared across browsers.
Session cookies are deleted when the browser session ends.
If a cookie is received for an expired session, a new session is created that uses the same session cookie.
Empty sessions aren't retained—the session must have at least one value set into it to persist the session across requests. When a session isn't retained, a new session ID is generated for each new request.
The app retains a session for a limited time after the last request. The app either sets the session timeout or uses the default value of 20 minutes. Session state is ideal for storing user data that's specific to a particular session but where the data doesn't require permanent storage across sessions.
Session data is deleted either when the ISession.Clear implementation is called or when the session expires.
There's no default mechanism to inform app code that a client browser has been closed or when the session cookie is deleted or expired on the client.

**The in-memory cache provider stores session data in the memory of the server where the app resides. In a server farm scenario:**

-Use sticky sessions to tie each session to a specific app instance on an individual server. Azure App Service uses Application Request Routing (ARR) to enforce sticky sessions by default. However, sticky sessions can affect scalability and complicate web app updates. A better approach is to use a Redis or SQL Server distributed cache, which doesn't require sticky sessions. For more information, see [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

-The session cookie is encrypted via IDataProtector. Data Protection must be properly configured to read session cookies on each machine. For more information, see ASP.NET Core Data Protection and Key storage providers.

**Configure session state**
The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session package, which is included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage, provides middleware for managing session state. To enable the session middleware, Startup must contain:

- Any of the IDistributedCache memory caches. The IDistributedCache implementation is used as a backing store for session. For more information, see [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
- A call to AddSession in ConfigureServices.
- A call to UseSession in Configure.

The following code shows how to set up the in-memory session provider with a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

---

Updated answer  as requested

---

Singletons in web environment aren't always that straightforward to create and use.

In web-applications, we might be considering the usage of three kinds of singletons:

1. Single instance per web-request
2. Single instance per user (session)
3. Single instance per whole web application( Most frequently used)

The first two cases aren't really an issue; What I'm really interested in is the third point, which is “Single instance per whole web application” which might be little tricky sometimes.

Usually, the standard Singleton pattern would apply as by default there is only one worker. A problem I've faced a couple of times during a few of my projects is - how to implement a Singleton in a multiple worker threads environment. If we have only one worker thread, implementing Singleton isn't really an issue as all web requests will share a static instance of it across the whole worker thread; the only problem is how to secure it as it's still a multi threaded environment, and this can be simply prevented by adding a "lock" as in the example below.

```js
public class Singleton {
    static Singleton instance = null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance {
        get {
            lock (padlock) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work well when we use one worker process in the application pool, but these days, most of the current server platforms do have multi-core processors, and with one working process, we won't really get the most of it.

An example of a Singleton for which multiple working processes might be an issue is the File Logger class – when each request would write some data to the same file. We could imagine what would happen if two "singletons" would try to write to the same file at the same time.

To solve this problem, we have to communicate between worker threads so all of them would be accessing a singleton which would exist in only one of them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohit for the explanation of User Sessions. As its describe for different user different session will be created. As my service is singleton, how it share its resources for transaction operation for all the sessions. How it ensure not to violate the singleton principle while serving multiple request at the same time.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Basically you would be sharing a single object(singleton object) across all your session , only thing which you need to maintain is concurrency.  Hope it helps.